# Redesign of megamenu

Tags: navigation, information-architecture, mega-menu

I've been asked to redesign a mega menu.

The mega menu lists selected child items from a particular parent in the IA, but not all children. There must therefore be an option to 'view all' from a particular branch in the mega menu.

The two options open to me are:
[image]

1. There is no page for a generic 'Household goods' but there are pages for individual sub headings which the user can access by clicking 'View all' at the end of each list "show me a page where I can browse all household goods of type X".
2. There are no pages for each sub category but there is a page for 'Household goods' which lists an assortment of household goods "show me a page that lists everything".

I can see pros and cons for each but I was wondering if there is specific evidence that would help me favour one over the other?

Comment: What are your mobile friendliness requirements?

Comment: need to be accessible on mobile. There is an evidence base I'm looking at from NnGroup.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much categories You have, it's possible to structuring menu into levels and tabs.

Significant in designing this type of menu is UI, i think about specific sizes between elements, in order to obtain readability and ease in navigating.

Another solution may be going back and re-categorizing elements to minimize the number of choices

An example from the Intel site:

[image]